# Firestore/Python - get() function to access a document fails in GCP Cloud Function

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access a document in Firestore like this:

```py
from google.cloud import firestore

def check_stuff(document_id, update_time):
    firestore_client = firestore.Client()
    doc_ref = firestore_client.collection(u'TestCollection').document(document_id)
    print(f"Ref OK")
    document = doc_ref.get()
    print(f"Doc OK")

    if document.exists:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It prints the first print ("Ref OK") but not the following one. Instead I get this error, which I don't really understand. I seems to comes from the get() function itself:

> Exception on / [POST] Traceback (most recent call last): File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/functions_framework/**init**.py", line 171, in view_func function(data, context) File "/workspace/main.py", line 110, in main check = check_stuff(document_id, update_time) File "/workspace/main.py", line 87, in check_stuff document = document_ref.get() File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", line 370, in get data = _helpers.decode_dict(document_pb.fields, self._client) File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 318, in decode_dict return {key: decode_value(value, client) for key, value in value_fields.items()} File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 318, in  return {key: decode_value(value, client) for key, value in value_fields.items()} File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/_helpers.py", line 276, in decode_value value_type = value._pb.WhichOneof("value_type") AttributeError: _pb

I checked that the collection truly exists, as well as the document in it. No problem here.

My code is located on a Google Cloud Function, called by Firestore Trigger (`write` trigger on the same document). The code works locally on my machine but not on GCP. It doesn't fail every time. It seems to fail only with certain document_id (even if they exist).

Python is 3.7 and google-cloud-firestore==2.0.1

Comment: Can you try `collection(...).stream()` and print the documents you receive?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
    
    def check_stuff(document_id, update_time):
        db = firestore.Client()
        doc_ref = db.collection(u'TestCollection').document(u'{document_id}')
        print(f"Ref OK")
        document_status = doc_ref.get()
        print(f"Doc OK")
    
        if document.exists:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Just try to use .where and the filter queries

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/listen

Or Get Reference of this one

```
# Create an Event for notifying main thread.
callback_done = threading.Event()

# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(f'Received document snapshot: {doc.id}')
    callback_done.set()

doc_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'SF')

# Watch the document
doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

Comment: The problem is actually bigger and more complex to me. See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73223848/access-to-firestore-fails-randomly-through-different-cloud-functions